# Unity3d and vuforia detecting if target appears

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am new here so I want to ask my first question.
I am using unity3d and vuforia for augmented reality.

I already set up AR camera on my scene and target image and object and works perfectly.

I am trying to play a sound when my 3d model appears on stage but without any luck.

So far I tried to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4u177CpPbp8 but in the line `public class PlaySoundOnImageTarget : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler` comes with an error on ITrackableEventHandler.

It's red colored and when I am moving my mouse on this it says "error CS0103: the name ITrackableEventHandler does not exist in the current context".

I tried to write the full code but a lot of lines come with almost the same errors.

Also, I tried this one: [https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/unity-how-can-i-play-audio-when-targets-get-detected]

Any help, please?

I am using unity3d 5.4.2f2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to include Vuforia before you can use it.

You can do so by placing `Using Vuforia;` at the top of your screen

Next time you might also want to read through the pages of Vuforia [as they already solve this](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/creating-ar-trackables/can-not-find-itrackableeventhandler-class) and a lot of other very basic errors you might walk into in the near future.

Comment: I am Sooooo noob... Thanks a lot @MX D!